# why this command does not work: cd `echo -n "~"`

Tags: bash, cd

Running the command

```
cd \`echo -n "~"\`
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: cd: ~: No such file or directory
```

What's the problem if `'cd ~'` works fine?

Comment: How force interpolation when do: cd \`cat test\` where test has ~ inside?

Comment: See my answer. In short, this situation demands the `eval` keyword. Though that's not safe practice in this case. It's similar to a SQL vulnerability, where the input can easily contain shell keywords.

Comment: @piojo: yeah, you'd have to manually parse the string if you wanted to safely expand `~` in untrustworthy data.  Letting the shell do it would mean it would also expand things like `$(rm -rf ~/ && sudo rm -rf / && echo pwned)`.

Comment: @EugenKonkov: use `set -x` to have the shell trace what it's doing.  So you can sometimes see which order quote-removal and expansions happen in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that bash does not do an additional expansion after command substitution. So while `cd ~` is expanded the way you want, `cd $(echo '~')` does not.

There is a keyword called `eval` that was created for this sort of situation--it forces the command line to be expanded (*eval*uated) again. If you use `eval` on that line, it forces the `~` to be expanded into the user directory, even though the normal time for expansion has already passed. (Because the `~` does not exist until the echo command is run, and at that point, it's too late for expansion.)

```
eval cd `echo -n "~"`
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do `cd ~`, the shell expands `~` to your home directory before executing the command. But if you use double quotes (`"~"`), then this is taken as a literal string and not expanded.

You can see the difference:

```
$ echo ~
/home/username
$ echo "~"
~
```

In order to have `~` expanded by the shell, you need to remove the double quotes.

The escaping behaviour of double quotes is described in the Bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html

Comment: @Grodriguez If I'm not mistaken, the OP meant to ask why is "cd ~" not expanded. After all, the OP is trying to generate a command.

Answer (score 0):

You will also get the same issue if you simply do `cd "~"`:

```
$ cd "~"
bash: cd: ~: No such file or directory
```

`cd` doesn't understand that `~` is special. It tries, and fails, to find a directory literally called `~`.

The reason that `cd ~` works is that `bash` edits the command before running it. `bash` replaces `cd ~` with `cd $HOME`, and then expands `$HOME` to get `cd /home/YourUsername`.

Therefore,

```
cd `echo -n "~"`
```

becomes

```
cd "~"
```